# How can I find out why/when a Python object loses attributes?

Tags: python, pygtk

**Update 2013-02-08**

I have an idea now why I haven't been able to reproduce this problem in a small piece of test code. In a small program, Python's garbage collector isn't very active. I believe the problem is that Python is collecting some objects that are only referenced in GObject. I think it's a regression involving [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92955), or a new similar bug.

I figured this out because I encountered the same problem again, but with my own class (which has references only from GObject objects) -- this time the entire **dict** is getting wiped out on the object. Uf I use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13520054/182642) to monitor one of the attributes that dissappears, it doesn't disappear! It seems the extra reference keeps the attributes around. That smells like a garbage collector problem. I confirmed this by having the object add itself to a global list during initialization... that also fixes the problem as it occurs now.

### Original Problem

I am experiencing some bizarre behavior with a PyGTK GUI. I have an object which is consistently losing a large number of attributes. I am trying to determine if this is a bug in my code, the Python interpreter, or PyGTK.

I make no calls to `delattr()`. I have tried detecting if anything is calling the `__delattr__()` method of my object by overriding `__delattr__()` with code that always raises an exception. I am able to reproduce the event which causes the object to lose its attributes but the exception is never raised. I'm not sure of another way to find out what function calls (if any) are causing the object to lose attributes.

The object in question is working perfectly at all times up until it suddenly loses attributes I'm trying to access.

The attribute loss occurs consistently after performing some actions in the GUI that have nothing to do with the object that is losing attributes. I discovered it by accident; there may be other actions that cause the object to lose its attributes.

I have added `print id(self)` to the method which access the disappearing attribute. The id that is printed is the same before and after the attribute disappears.

Any suggestions on how to track down the source of this problem?

**Reference code below:** *(Note: I will update this code if/when I come up with a simplified test case that reproduces the problem. Right now the total code required to reproduce the bug is too big to post here.)*

Here is the class for my object which loses its attributes. This is obviously a minimized version of the real functional code, but I am using this for debugging and the problem still occurs.

It is a subclass of my custom `MenuBar` class.
Note that the `on_file_import__activate()` method is connected to the signal for the menu item by one of the parent classes.

```
class FluidClassManagerWindowMenu(MenuBar):
    menu_items = [("File",("Import",))]

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # XXX: different name than self.parent to see if it stops disappearing 
        self._xxx_my_parent = parent
        MenuBar.__init__(self, parent)

    def __delattr__(self,attr):
        # XXX: trying to find the cause for lost attributes
        traceback.print_stack()

    def on_file_import__activate(self, widget=None, data=None):
        # XXX: this is the same before and after the attributes disappear
        print id(self)
        # XXX: print the list of attributes to see what disappears
        print dir(self)
        # XXX: this works until the _xxx_my_parent attribute disappears
        print self._xxx_my_parent
```

If you're curious, here is the complete source for my MenuBar class.  It is a [pygtkhelpers](http://packages.python.org/pygtkhelpers/) `SlaveView`, which inherits from `GObject`. The pygtkhelpers delegate does the automagic signal connection to the `on_file_import__activate` method above.

```
class MenuBar(pygtkhelpers.delegates.SlaveView):        
    def __init__(self, parent):
        SlaveView.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent

    def create_ui(self):
        menu_bar = gtk.MenuBar()
        menu_bar.set_pack_direction(gtk.PACK_DIRECTION_LTR)

        for menu_name, items in self.menu_items:
            menu = gtk.Menu()
            submenu = gtk.MenuItem(menu_name)
            submenu.set_submenu(menu)
            for item_name in items:
                if not item_name:
                    menu.append(gtk.MenuItem())
                    continue
                menuitem = gtk.MenuItem(item_name)
                fixed_item_name = item_name.lower().replace(' ','_')
                fixed_menu_name = menu_name.lower().replace(' ','_')
                attr_name = '%s_%s' % (fixed_menu_name,fixed_item_name)
                # set an attribute like self.edit_vial_layout
                # so pygtkhelpers can find the widget to connect the signal from
                setattr(self,attr_name,menuitem)
                menu.append(menuitem)
            menu_bar.append(submenu)
        self.vbox = gtk.VBox()
        self.vbox.pack_start(menu_bar)
        self.vbox.show_all()
        self.widget.add(self.vbox)
```

**List of attributes which disappear from the object**:

`'_model', '_props', '_toplevel', '_xxx_my_parent',  'file_import', 'parent', 'slaves', 'testtesttest', 'vbox', 'widget'`

The attribute `parent` is what originally was disappearing; I tried assigning its value to `_xxx_my_parent` in
`ManagerWindowMenu.__init__()` but it disappears as well. I also added a new attribute in `MenuBar.__init__` that I never access, called `testtesttest`, and it disappears too.

Comment: Maybe a new object is being bound to the same name you're expecting? Post the code sample

Comment: Daenyth, if a new object is getting bound, he may still have those attributes set to some default instead of 'missing them altogether'. But yes, more information will definitely help.

Comment: or maybe the function that call `delattr` (if exist) is also catching all the exception raised, try using `traceback` module in `__delattr__` you can put `traceback.print_stack()` instead of raising an exception , this will print all the function calls if the `__delattr__` is called.

Comment: @Daenyth I printed `self.id` in the function which tries to access the disappearing attribute (on `self`) -- the id is the same as it was when the attribute has not yet disappeared. I'll try to isolate the relevant code and post a code sample.

Comment: @singularity Good idea on printing the stack. I added that to the `__delattr__` method. Unfortunately I do not see any stack trace appear from the time the attribute is accessible to when it has disappeared.

Comment: What is the type of the object missing the attributes? What are the names of the missing attributes? How many are going missing?

Comment: @Daenyth @detly I added the list of disappearing attributes as well as some code to my question.

Comment: I am having the same problem using pygtk - but the class that loses attributes in my case does not inherit from any gtk class, its my own. This problem is completely confounding. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13321448/694195

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that objects in PyGTK often inherit from GObject. There is likely activity occuring within the GObject framework that is causing you to lose the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem. I had a class (SearchWorker) that built a widget for adding to the GUI at runtime. In that widget, there was a button whose "clicked" signal was connected to one of the SearchWorker functions. Whenever the "clicked" signal was fired, many of the attributes of the SearchWorker self object were gone.

I was creating the SearchWorker object in another handler of a different class like this:

```
worker = SearchWorker()
```

I presume that once that handler exited something odd happened to the object behind the worker reference. Changing the creation of SearchWorker to:

```
self.worker = SearchWorker()
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How strange. BTW, using `delattr` and `__delattr__` call is not very common, so I suspect if you are not dealing with two different objects by themselves, getting one while expecting another. Also it may not be a problem with the interpreter, it would crash at much lower level if there was a problem.

Comment: I added `print id(self)` to the method and it prints the same number before and after the attributes have disappeared. Does that rule out getting a different object?