# Why is the traceback for an AttributeError raised from a property of a QObject flawed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, qt4, pyqt4

Apparently when an `AttributeError` is raised from a `property` of a `QObject` then the traceback includes a different `AttributeError` instead namely one referring to the property itself.

Running the following code

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore


class MyObject(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__(parent)

    @property
    def invalid_property(self):
        raise AttributeError('test')
        # raise TypeError('test')

    def invalid_method(self):
        raise AttributeError('test')

obj = MyObject()
obj.invalid_property
# obj.invalid_method()
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    obj.invalid_property
AttributeError: 'MyObject' object has no attribute 'invalid_property'
```

That is the original `AttributeError` is replaced by a different one in the traceback.

I tried the same raising a `TypeError` which works just fine, as well as raising the `AttributeError` from a conventional method which works fine too.

If I inherit from `object` instead of `QObject` then the original `AttributeError` appears in the traceback too.

So what's happening here? Is a different `AttributeError` raised or is the original one's message just altered? And why does this happen? Is this a bug or intended behavior?

---

Related:

- [Question at stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321448/python-classes-losing-attributes)
- [Question at riverbankcomputing.com](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2011-April/029673.html)

Comment: Sounds like it might be falling back on a `__getattr__` method after your property fails to produce an attribute value.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with PyQt. It's normal Python behaviour for any class that implements `__getattr__` and raises `AttributeError` in a getter property.